# How to install Ubuntu on two different hard drives

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive, home-directory

I have a laptop with a UEFI boot system with two hard drives installed. The first hard drive is a 35GB SSD, and the second is a 500GB mechanical drive. In terms of installation I have no problem. I figured it out from the start, only changing the way that Ubuntu boots. I want to put my system files on the SSD and my /home directory on the other drive, so that the SSD won't fill up too quickly. Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. It sounds like you want to install Ubuntu, and you want to put your system files on the SSD and your /home directory on the other drive. You tagged the question with the "dual-boot" tag, yet you didn't mention any other OS on the laptop. Do you want to have 2 different operating systems on your laptop or just Ubuntu?

Comment: No, am only want have ubuntu, i don't use another system

Answer (score 3):

You want to create a separate `/home` partition. This is most easily done during system installation by selecting the "something else" partitioning option and setting up `/home` on the spinning disk. You can do it after installing the OS, but this requires more effort. Numerous Web sites describe the process in detail. A Web search turns up quite a few, starting with:

- http://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/
- http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/separatehome
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
- http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: Thanks this is the answet y try whit the solution bye howtogeek any problem