# Do i choose install alongside windows 10 or something else?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

So I know this question may have been asked but I bring it up because I cant find a decent answer for my case and scenario. I have two hard-drives:

1. My C DRIVE is the main drive and has my windows 10 installed on it.
2. My second drive is my 1 TB hard-drive. The 1 TB is the hard-drive that i want to install Ubuntu on.

So in this case should I initially create a partition in the 1 TB (60 GB partition) and then choose "Alongside Windows" or should I not make any initial partition and just click "Something else."

Any feedback will be helpful and if possible can you please give me steps into ways of doing this.

Comment: **Personal opinion : [never trust automatic partitioning options in Ubuntu installers](http://askubuntu.com/a/412332/497359) Its buggy , do this instead [How to use manual partitioning](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)**

Comment: Thank you and yes i didnt initially understand how booting alongside windows would even get the file to install on the second hard drive but hopefully it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to chose 'Install alongside Windows 10'.  If it detected that Windows 10 was there, it will add it to the boot menu.  You should be given the option to select what drive to install to.  If you have issues, let us know.

When you select 'Something else', you will be required to do a lot more, so if you're not familiar with Ubuntu installing (the advanced way) then don't choose this.

If you really want to choose 'Something Else...' then try this question: [Should I choose to Install alongside windows 8 or something else](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412319/should-i-choose-to-install-alongside-windows-8-or-something-else?rq=1)

Comment: I will try the automatic first but if i have issues i will move on to manual partitioning. Could i not just initially create a partition in my 1TB drive and then do boot alongside Windows?

Comment: So i tried these methods but it looks like I have an underlying problem. I asked a question before pertaining to an error i kept seeing that stopped me from accessing the ubuntu installer which was a "nouveau sched_error" and well i thought i may have fixed it but its still occuring and Ubuntu just freezes. Im worried this may have a bad affect on my computer in general...

Comment: The `grub-update` run on installation *will* detect Windows 10, regardless of option chosen.

Comment: It will, unless it's an EFI install and Ubuntu is BIOS (or the other way around)

Answer (score 1):

I will try to steer you in the right direction but this question is new to me. I always choose to install Ubuntu alongside of Windows when I'm dual booting.

It would make since to choose the "Something else." option seeing you want the Ubuntu on the 1 TB drive.

It should give you the option to create a partition for that drive or even detect another drive it available.

This may also help you get started...

[How to install Ubuntu on two different hard drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308011/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-two-different-hard-drives)

**Please mark this answer useful if you found it helpful**

Comment: Yup so i will try this but i do think they it would be best if i do it manually as it would make more sense